# Dictionary from XML based on parent and child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

I write an application in WPF and I have the following XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <EYE>
    <DAD>Blue</DAD>
    <MOM>Brown</MOM>
  </EYE>
  <HAIR>
    <DAD>Black</DAD>
    <MOM>Brown</MOM>
  </HAIR>
  <SKIN>
    <DAD>White</DAD>
    <MOM>White</MOM>
  </SKIN>
</NewDataSet>
```

I would like to read that XML into a dictionary so if I choose to read "DAD" data I would get:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"EYE", Blue},
    {"HAIR", Black},
    {"SKIN", White}
};
```

Is it possible, and if so, who can I do it?
Any code snippets would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really quite simple:

```
    var xd = XDocument.Parse(@"<NewDataSet>
  <EYE>
    <DAD>Blue</DAD>
    <MOM>Brown</MOM>
  </EYE>
  <HAIR>
    <DAD>Black</DAD>
    <MOM>Brown</MOM>
  </HAIR>
  <SKIN>
    <DAD>White</DAD>
    <MOM>White</MOM>
  </SKIN>
</NewDataSet>");

Dictionary<string, string> values =
    xd
        .Root
        .Elements()
        .ToDictionary(
            xe => xe.Name.LocalName,
            xe => xe.Element("DAD").Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<NewDataSet>" +
                    "<EYE>" +
                       "<DAD>Blue</DAD>" +
                       "<MOM>Brown</MOM>" +
                    "</EYE>" +
                    "<HAIR>" +
                       "<DAD>Black</DAD>" +
                       "<MOM>Brown</MOM>" +
                    "</HAIR>" +
                    "<SKIN>" +
                       "<DAD>White</DAD>" +
                       "<MOM>White</MOM>" +
                    "</SKIN>" +
                "</NewDataSet>";

            XElement dataset = XElement.Parse(xml);

            Dictionary<string, string> dadDict = dataset.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y.Element("DAD"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you grouping and then doing `.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: When you have a <string,string> in a dictionary you will get a compiler error if you don't use y.FirstOrDefault().  You could use var rather than Dictionary<string,string>.  When a dictionary is <string, List<string>> then use y.ToList() to get rid of compiler error.